# Session is not being set in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.7.2

I am working on a project which is using

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["XYZSession"]="abcValue";
```

in a get request which gets a parameter from the link being opened.

The problem is, when I open the link by right-clicking on it and selecting the option open in new tab or by pressing the <kbd>Ctrl-Key+Mouse</kbd> left click, it doesn't save session, but when I paste a link in search box of browser and hit enter and then the session is being saved now.

I am using

- C#, .NET Framework 4.7.x
- Visual Studio 2017
- Hosted on IIS Server

Comment: Hi @NitinSawant Thanks for your quick response,
The link is a referral Link which contains a code with it and pass it to action and then in that action I go into database and get more details about the referral in a model and then store that model in session. and then it redirects user to signup page but the session got reset. And I need that session to use it for further use while the transaction is being created.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue? I am also having same error - session is null while setting up authentication in an old .net framework based mvc 5 web app.